# Center DIV Horizontally and Vertically

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="metaboxdet">
    <div class="metd">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fvueL00n/2/

the problem here is I cant center the div "metd" horizontally and vertically. I have tried adjusting the top, bottom, left and right but it return a not so accurate results. Is there a way where i can center horizontally and vertically dynamically.

please check the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fvueL00n/2/) to see it in action. Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div) should help with vertical align.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As discussed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div), you can add a helper element with `height:100%` and `display:inline-block` with `vertical-align:middle`, and change the container to be `display:inline-block` with `vertical-align:middle`

```
.helper{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
/*container*/
.metd{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Here's the code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/7npsfx3c/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use table layout (you should also apply `display:table;` to the `.metaboxdet` container):

```
.metd {display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fvueL00n/3/)

Comment: hey @suslov, your code works perfectly in JSFiddle! Thanks. jsut a quick question, does it work in different browser? It works perfectly in chrome but not in firefox. Am i the only one having issues? here's the link.
http://alphaomega.bendaggers.com/

Comment: @SaraAriadneFontana: It's kinda strange, works fine in Safari (the issue is due to `height` property, container just is not taking full height).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but it will not support [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

```
.metaboxdet {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Vendor prefixes are left for the reader to add for completeness.

Comment: that's something that i haven't heard. flexbox.

Comment: You can get started with flexbox with the link I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

edited your markup to:

```
<div style="display:table;" class="metaboxdet">
  <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;" class="metd">
    <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and your css is unchanged you can remove not needed css:

```
.metaboxdet {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:9;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color: #292484;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #292484, #dc4225);
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.metd {position:relative; margin:0px auto; width:70%; }
.metd h1 {color: #FFF; font-size:40px; font-style:italic; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); line-height:1.2em;}
```

or check this I've edited you fiddle to this

https://jsfiddle.net/fvueL00n/2/

and if you don't want there that extra div you can align `h1` directly in `div` as well

for more refer [howtocenterincss.com](http://howtocenterincss.com/#contentType=div&horizontal=center&vertical=middle&browser.IE=6)